# One J1 visa for both my internship and the supervision of a bachelor thesis

Tags: visas, usa, germany

I’m a fourth year food technology student form Germany and I am planning to do my internship and my bachelor thesis in America.

I already found a company which will supervise me and I’m the the process to apply for a J1 Visa now. This lead to a question my counselor couldn’t answer me.

My internship will have a duration of 20 weeks (March 2019 - July 2019). The supervision of the bachelor thesis will start in August 2019 and last till December 2019.

Can I apply for one Visa for the whole 10 months or do I have to apply for two separate Visas because I change from the status of an intern to a research scholar or can I keep the status of an intern while working on my bachelor thesis?